# geojson ignored when using mapbox

Tags: mapbox

why does mapbox ignore my geoJson marker-symbol, marker-color, and marker-size? if for whatever reason it ignores, how do you set either?

**sample geoJson:**

```
"properties": {
      "id": 578202,
      "name": "University of North Carolina at Charlotte",
      "marker-symbol": "marker",
      "marker-color": "#ff8888",
      "marker-size": "small",
      "description": 1
    }
```

**script:**

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {

           var popupContent = feature.properties.name +'project(s)';
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {
                closeButton: true,
                minWidth: 225
            });     
        }
    });
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', '', {
        attributionControl: false
    });
    geojson.addTo(map);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because `L.GeoJSON` doesn't automaticly know that you want to set the marker options, so if it encounters a Point feature, it simply adds a default marker. If you want to do something special with point features, you can use the `pointToLayer` function of `L.GeoJSON`, check the following example:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geoJson, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latLng) {
        return L.marker(latLng, {
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon(feature.properties)
        });
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

The only problem with this is that it also adds all the other properties as options of the markericon. Personally i would write some logic so that only the relevant properties get added to the icon options.

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3OJPXxOYdzX8mSnjEb90?p=preview

As tmcw pointed out in the comments (see below): you could use `L.mapbox.featureLayer`, it does exactly what you're trying to accomplish with `L.GeoJSON` without having to resort to the `pointToLayer` method i described above and it only uses the appropriate properties. It can even load your data for you so you can do away with jQuery's `$.getJSON`. Win/win situation if you ask me. You can simply do the following and you're set:

```
L.mapbox.featureLayer(url).addTo(map);
```

Here's the working example of this on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Og6tuYDIkTX7ftedoR3C?p=preview

Comment: Additionally, you can use `L.mapbox.featureLayer` for this to happen automatically.

Comment: I see, thanks for mentioning that, i wasn't aware. Looking at the source i see it only assigns the appropriate properties to the icon, great solution. That in combination with the built in XHR is a better solution than using jQuery with L.GeoJSON and pointToLayer. I would opt for that if it was me. You guys do great work over at Mapbox, i'm a big fan. I'll add that to my answer. (If you don't mind).